# Error: Failed to build the bibliography via biber {vitae}

Tags: r-markdown, tinytex

I am trying to reproduce the cv using the `vitae` package and keep running into an odd error when it comes to generating the bibliography. It was working previously, but when I try to execute the code today it keeps producing the following output:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'cv.blg'
INFO - Reading 'cv.bcf'
INFO - Found 4 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'C:/Users/Joe Roberts/Documents/automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'C:/Users/Joe Roberts/Documents/automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib' to C:/Users/Joe\ Roberts/Documents/automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'C:/Users/Joe\ Roberts/Documents/automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'C:/Users/Joe\ Roberts/Documents/automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Error: Failed to build the bibliography via biber
Execution halted
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 237.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'roberts2018u-x6o8ySG0sC' undefined on input line 242.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'roberts2019d1gkVwhDpl0C' undefined on input line 242.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'roberts2019IjCSPb-OGe4C' undefined on input line 242.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'roberts2019Tyk-4Ss8FVUC' undefined on input line 242.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `cv.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                cv
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had the same issue, it used to work, then some update, and it no longer works. It appears the source of the issue is the *space* in your path (Users/Joe Roberts/Documents/) I had the same problem because our organisational db automatically include spaces. I have x2 workarounds:

**First workaround (annoying one):** save your files locally in a path that doesnt have space in it. For me this was taking it out of our org db and saving it on desktop. I know, very lame, so the 2nd one is better!

**Second workaround:** In your setup code chunk in the .Rmd, add code to copy citation files into temporary locations where biber can read from:

E.g.:

```
citations_1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".bib")
file.copy(from = here::here("automated_cv/cv/roberts-published.bib"), to = citations_1)
```

I guessed the filepath from your error message by the way, so you may need to edit that, but essentially this should help!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you call the package `biblatex` like this:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Please use the code highlighting, like `hi`